# How can I retrieve data from an external XML file and place it in an HTML file?

Tags: javascript, xml, external

I am trying to retrieve data from an XML file that is not located on my site's server, and then use that data fro various things, such as charts. Here is one example: http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=40.78158&lon=-73.96648&FcstType=dwml. This is an XML file with the weather data for central park. I want to retrieve the data that is in the `<value>`tag, which is in the `<pressure>` tag, so I can create a graph with barometric pressure. I would prefer to do this with JavaScript, but I don't think it's possible to do so when the file isn't on my server.

Note: I *do not* want a different solution to retrieve the pressure data from somewhere else, because I want to retrieve other pieces of data from other XML files as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an [interesting article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xmlajaxpt3/index.html) about using Yahoo! Pipes to transform Xml weather data to JSON and use the result in a web page without need for any server side stuff (PHP, curl, etc.).

*EDIT*

Being new to jQuery myself, I a had to dig a little more to find out that (almost) everything described in the first article can be condensed down to

```
$.getJSON("<your Yahoo pipes url here>&_callback=?", function (data) {
    alert(data.value.items[0].data[0].parameters.wordedForecast.text[0]);
});
```

using jQuerys builtin **JSONP**.

**Pitfall!**

Beware that Yahoo expects the `callback` url param to be named **_callback**

Nice summary on [Cross-domain communications with JSONP](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/) which helped a lot to come up with this answer.

Comment: I think that's the perfect solution, however, I can't get it to work [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BvBzL/1/). Can you try and figure out what went wrong? I know that the pipe is working, so it must be the JavaScript.

Comment: Good news everyone! It's even easier because jQuery has all the hacky bits already built in ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If your javascript code is on a server (as opposed to a mobile device), have PHP code load the xml, escape it and insert it into the HTML page. Then you just have to grab that in your code and process it with DOMParser.

Comment: Sorry, I need a more detailed explanation. I have yet to learn any of the web programming languages like PHP. (next on my list :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use curl to pull the data to your server and act on it from there.

```
curl -o data.txt "http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=40.78158&lon=-73.96648&FcstType=dwml"
```

This will  give you the information in a file called data.txt. You could then either parse it server side and then just give the bits of data needed, or make the whole file available to your client, since they are both now in the same domain.

Comment: That sounds good, but I've never heard of curl. How do I implement this, specifically?

Comment: Again, difficult to say without knowing what your server side set up is.

Comment: It's a school server, so I don't have much control. I know the following about it: it doesn't support forms, it supports FTP, it supports JavaScript, and it supports CSS.

Comment: My guess is you guys are using PHP on the server side and javascript is only available in the client browser. If it turns out you are using node.js let me know and I can post another solution. Otherwise take a look at this link for how to use curl from php. [link]http://www.paul-norman.co.uk/2009/06/asynchronous-curl-requests

Comment: So I would embed that into the HTMl, and put the script above in a php file, and then finally retrieve the information? Sorry if I seem really dumb; I have never used PHP before. thanks